# angularJS Custom Filter to pull out a particular value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am printing out a list using ng-repeat in the following way :

```
<ul ng-controller="myController">
    <li ng-repeat="somename in somenames">
        <a>{{ somename.name }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and the values are coming from the controller like :

```
myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', 
  function($scope) {
      $scope.somenames = [{ name: 'group1'},{name: 'group2'},{name: 'admin'},{name: 'group4'}];
  }
]);
```

I want to implement a filter such the value 'admin' always remains at the top of the list and the rest of the names are sorted alphabetically right after. Here is my current work on jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/3353/ (nothing much, I am sort of stuck). Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

```
myApp.filter('FirstAdminThenAlphabetic', function () {
    return function (array, order) {
        var comparator;

        if (order === 'descending') {
            comparator = function (elm1, elm2) {                    
                return elm1.name < elm2.name;
            }
        } else {
            comparator = function (elm1, elm2) {                    
                return elm1.name > elm2.name;
            }
        }

        return array.filter(function (elm) {
            return elm.name === 'admin';
        }).concat(
            array.filter(function (elm) {
                return elm.name !== 'admin';
            }).sort(comparator)
        );

    }; 
});
```

You basically filter out all admins and sort that list, than concatenate it to a list where you filtered out anything but admins. I added a function for ascending or descending ordering. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/3358/)

Comment: I am getting TypeErrors on my machine while I implement this. Can this be because there are 2 different filter methods with same name? One comes from angular and the other is basically a array.filter() ? Any help? Or alternative is welcome..

Comment: Can you see which line is giving type errors? Are you using any other libraries? Is the jsfiddle working for you? Which browser do you use? Array.filter is only supported from ie9 onwards. For legacy browsers you can use the shim on this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter